# Laptop Asus P50IJ with Intel 4500M GMA output going to a Dell 1907FP external monitor will not allow proper resolution

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, lcd

I just purchased an Asus P50IJ-X2 laptop which has a Intel GMA 4500M video card running Windows 7.  At work I output this laptop to a Dell 1907FP LCD which has a maximum resolution of 1280x1024.  Not matter what I do the Windows will not allow the laptop to set a resolution higher than 1024x768 to this LCD monitor.

Ive even gone to the extent of downloading PowerStrip to create a custom driver for my monitor thinking Windows was having a hard time seeing the available resolutions it would accept.  However, PowerStrip read the registry and properly sees the monitor and what its capable of so I'm now at a complete loss as to why Windows 7 will not allow me to set/use a 1280x1024 resolution for this external monitor (as my last laptop did running Vista).

The Intel documentation indicates that the GMA 4500M should be able to run up to a 2560x1600 max res.

The [Dell 1907FP specification](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/1907fp/en/about.htm#Specifications) states it can run up to a 1280x1024 res.

However no matter what the computer will not allow me to set higher than a 1024x768.
I'm completely baffled but I would really like to be able to output this laptop to a reasonable resolution, 1024x768 makes me feel like I'm using my mom's computer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are some attached images:

Image 1 - This image is from PowerStrip which shows the monitors max accepted resolution and at the top right the max res my PC currently allows.

[image: Powerstrip]

Image 2 - This shows my Windows 7 resolution picker.

[image: Resolution picker]

Image 3 - The 'List all modes' option taken from the Screen Resolution > Advanced Settings > List All Modes.

[image: All modes]

Image 4 - Monitor information from registry read by PowerStrip, this shows the laptop is able to read the necessary info from the LCD monitor.

[image: Monitor information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bizarre driver conflict and the fact that my output was going through a KVM.  I upgraded the Intel VGA driver to the latest, unplugged the monitor from the KVM and went directly to the laptop.  After doing this the PC fully realized all the possible resolutions and allowed me to select 1280x1024.  Once this was complete, I went back to the KVM and all was happy in the world.

In case in matters I went from driver 8.15.10.1872  to 8.15.10.2008

Answer (score 1):

All specifications on the notebook indicate a max resolution of 1366x768.  What the chip may be capable of and what is actually implemented may be two different things.  Among other factors is how much video RAM the chipset has access to.

Comment: Is there a way I can determine how much RAM the chipset has access to?  Even though the notebook resolution max is 1366x768 I wouldn't imagine a modern day laptop manufacturer restricting external resolution settings like that.  That just seems like a major step backwards on pretty standard technology.